# FlinkSQL - select last

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I would like to emit last record of a time window. This can easily be done with `maxBy` in regular Flink but I cannot get it to work through SQL API. What I want is:

```
SELECT LAST(attribute) FROM [table]
  GROUP BY key, TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

which behaves similar to

```
ds.keyBy(key)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1)))
  .maxBy(x -> x.getTs())
```

Any way to achieve that in SQL API?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in function for this in Flink yet, but you could implement a user-defined aggregate function for this.

You need to adjust the query a little bit and pass the timestamp field in the aggregation function, because SQL does not assume an order of the rows of a `GROUP BY` group:

```
SELECT last_by(attribute, ts) FROM [table]
  GROUP BY key, TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

I refer to the documentation for details [how to implement](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/functions/udfs.html#aggregation-functions) and [register](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/sql/create.html#create-function) a user-defined aggregation function.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly how I wanted to achieve that yesterday, I came accross problems with types, would be cool if you could help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027612/create-flinksql-udf-with-generic-return-type

Comment: also: do you see a simpler way of getting last record of a time window? using e.g. standard SQL OVER expression?

Comment: I don't think so. The `OVER` clause would not aggregate the data, i.e., it would emit one result row for every input row, which is not what you want if I understood your requirements correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is `LAST_VALUE` function in Flink, built in.

Check:  https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/