# Create FlinkSQL UDF with generic return type

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I would like to define function `MAX_BY` that takes value of type `T` and ordering parameter of type `Number` and returns max element from window according to ordering (of type `T`). I've tried

```
public class MaxBy<T> extends AggregateFunction<T, Tuple2<T, Number>> {

    @Override
    public T getValue(Tuple2<T, Number> tuple) {
        return tuple.f0;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<T, Number> createAccumulator() {
        return Tuple2.of(null, 0L);
    }

    public void accumulate(Tuple2<T, Number> acc, T value, Number order) {
        if (order.doubleValue() > acc.f1.doubleValue()) {
            acc.f0 = value;
            acc.f1 = order;
        }
    }
}
```

but I cannot register such function using `TableEnvironment.registerFunction`. Underneath Flink uses `TypeInformation` to match types within SQL query and with such definition it cannot determine types (at least that's what I suppose). I saw that it is possible to provide several `accumulate` functions but still - I think return type must be same for each overloaded method.

Built-in aggregation functions work similarly to what I want to achieve - `MAX` can take arbitrary column type and return the same type. That's why I suppose I should be able to do it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Flink doesn't support aggregation functions with flexible return types. For the `MAX` function, the internal implementation defines the core logic independent of the the type and then creates an implementation for every supported type ([see code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0ab1549f52f1f544e8492757c6b0d562bf50a061/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/functions/aggfunctions/MaxAggFunction.scala)).

Internally, `MAX` is then mapped to the right implementation, depending on the type.

I don't think that's possible if you define and register a function as user-defined aggregation function.